# How to align the label to centre?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tikz-styles

I'm using `tikz` to draw my Neural Net architecture. The below snippet is for a single convolution block:

```
\pic[shift={ (1,0,0) }] at (pool_b2-east) 
    {RightBandedBox={
        name=ccr_b3,
        caption= ,
        xlabel={{ 256, 256 }},
        zlabel=I/4,
        fill=\ConvColor,
        bandfill=\ConvReluColor,
        height=25,
        width={ 4.5 , 4.5 },
        depth=25
        }
    };
```

This builds the following:

[image]

How do I align the `zlabel` to the centre of the axis? The example I am following manages to get the zlabel at centre with the exact same code.

Thanks

edit:  Full code below:

```
\documentclass[border=8pt, multi, tikz]{standalone}
%\usepackage{blocks}
\usepackage{import}
\subimport{../../layers/}{init}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\def\ConvColor{rgb:yellow,5;red,2.5;white,5}
\def\ConvReluColor{rgb:yellow,5;red,5;white,5}
\def\PoolColor{rgb:red,1;black,0.3}
\def\UnpoolColor{rgb:blue,2;green,1;black,0.3}
\def\FcColor{rgb:blue,5;red,2.5;white,5}
\def\FcReluColor{rgb:blue,5;red,5;white,4}
\def\SoftmaxColor{rgb:magenta,5;black,7}


\newcommand{\copymidarrow}{\tikz \draw[-Stealth,line width =0.8mm,draw={rgb:blue,4;red,1;green,1;black,3}] (-0.3,0) -- ++(0.3,0);}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{connection}=[ultra thick,every node/.style={sloped,allow upside down},draw=\edgecolor,opacity=0.7]
\tikzstyle{copyconnection}=[ultra thick,every node/.style={sloped,allow upside down},draw={rgb:blue,4;red,1;green,1;black,3},opacity=0.7]

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Draw Encoder
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% conv1_1,conv1_2
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (0,0,0) {RightBandedBox={name=cr1,%
        xlabel={{"64","64"}},zlabel=I,fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=40,width={2,2},depth=40}};
%pool1
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (cr1-east) {Box={name=p1,%
        fill=\PoolColor,opacity=0.5,height=32,width=1,depth=32}};
%%%%%%%%%%
% conv2_1,conv2_2
\pic[shift={(1,0,0)}] at (p1-east) {RightBandedBox={name=cr2,%
        xlabel={{"128","128"}},zlabel=I/2,fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=32,width={3.5,3.5},depth=32}};
%pool2
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (cr2-east) {Box={name=p2,%
        fill=\PoolColor,opacity=0.5,height=25,width=1,depth=25}};
%%%%%%%%%%
% conv3_1,conv3_2
\pic[shift={(0.75,0,0)}] at (p2-east) {RightBandedBox={name=cr3,%
        xlabel={{"256","256"}},zlabel=I/4,fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=25,width={4.5,4.5},depth=25}};
%pool3
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (cr3-east) {Box={name=p3,%
        fill=\PoolColor,opacity=0.5,height=16,width=1,depth=16}};
%%%%%%%%%%
% conv4_1,conv4_2,conv4_3
\pic[shift={(0.5,0,0)}] at (p3-east) {RightBandedBox={name=cr4,%
        xlabel={{"512","512"}},zlabel=I/8,fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=16,width={6,6},depth=16}};
%pool4
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (cr4-east) {Box={name=p4,%
        fill=\PoolColor,opacity=0.5,height=8,width=1,depth=8}};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Bottleneck
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% conv5_1,conv5_2,conv5_3
\pic[shift={(0.75,0,0)}] at (p4-east) {RightBandedBox={name=cr5,caption=Bottleneck Conv,%
        xlabel={{"1024","1024"}},zlabel=I/16,fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=8,width={8,8},depth=8}};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Draw Decoder 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% unpool4, 
\pic[shift={(1.2,0,0)}] at (cr5-east) {Box={name=up4,%
        fill=\UnpoolColor,opacity=0.6,height=16,width=1,depth=16}};
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (up4-east) {RightBandedBox={name=ucr4,%
        xlabel={{"512","dummy"}},fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=16,width=6,depth=16}};
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (ucr4-east) {RightBandedBox={name=cat4,%
        xlabel={{"512",""}},fill={rgb:white,1;black,3},bandfill={rgb:white,1;black,2},opacity=0.2,height=16,width=6,depth=16}};    
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (cat4-east) {RightBandedBox={name=ucr4a,%
        xlabel={{"512","512"}},zlabel=I/8,fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=16,width={6,6},depth=16}};
%%%%%%%%%%
%% unpool3, 
\pic[shift={(1.5,0,0)}] at (ucr4a-east) {Box={name=up3,%
        fill=\UnpoolColor,opacity=0.6,height=25,width=1,depth=25}};
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (up3-east) {RightBandedBox={name=ucr3,%
        xlabel={{"256","dummy"}},fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=25,width=4.5,depth=25}};
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (ucr3-east) {RightBandedBox={name=cat3,%
        xlabel={{"256",""}},fill={rgb:white,1;black,3},bandfill={rgb:white,1;black,2},opacity=0.2,height=25,width=4.5,depth=25}};
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (cat3-east) {RightBandedBox={name=ucr3a,%
        xlabel={{"256","256"}},zlabel=I/4,fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=25,width={4.5,4.5},depth=25}};
%%%%%%%%%%
%% unpool2, 
\pic[shift={(1,0,0)}] at (ucr3a-east) {Box={name=up2,%
        fill=\UnpoolColor,opacity=0.6,height=32,width=1,depth=32}};
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (up2-east) {RightBandedBox={name=ucr2,%
        xlabel={{"128","dummy"}},fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=32,width=3.5,depth=32}};
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (ucr2-east) {RightBandedBox={name=cat2,%
        xlabel={{"128",""}},fill={rgb:white,1;black,3},bandfill={rgb:white,1;black,2},opacity=0.2,height=32,width=3.5,depth=32}};    
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (cat2-east) {RightBandedBox={name=ucr2a,%
        xlabel={{"128","128"}},zlabel=I/2,fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=32,width={3.5,3.5},depth=32}};
%%%%%%%%%%
%% unpool1, 
\pic[shift={(1.5,0,0)}] at (ucr2a-east) {Box={name=up1,%
        fill=\UnpoolColor,opacity=0.6,height=40,width=1,depth=40}};
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (up1-east) {RightBandedBox={name=ucr1,%
        xlabel={{"64","dummy"}},fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=40,width=2.5,depth=40}};
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (ucr1-east) {RightBandedBox={name=cat1,%
        xlabel={{"64",""}},fill={rgb:white,1;black,3},bandfill={rgb:white,1;black,2},opacity=0.2,height=40,width=2.5,depth=40}};  
\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (cat1-east) {RightBandedBox={name=ucr1a,%
        xlabel={{"64","64"}},fill=\ConvColor,bandfill=\ConvReluColor,%
        height=40,width={2.5,2.5},depth=40}};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Classifier 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pic[shift={(0.75,0,0)}] at (ucr1a-east) {Box={name=out,caption=Softmax,%
        zlabel=I,fill=\SoftmaxColor,height=40,width=1,depth=40}};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Draw connections
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw [connection]  (p1-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (cr2-west);
\draw [connection]  (p2-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (cr3-west);
\draw [connection]  (p3-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (cr4-west);
\draw [connection]  (p4-east)    -- node {\midarrow} (cr5-west);
\draw [connection]  (cr5-east)   -- node {\midarrow} (up4-west);
\draw [connection]  (ucr4a-east) -- node {\midarrow} (up3-west);
\draw [connection]  (ucr3a-east) -- node {\midarrow} (up2-west);
\draw [connection]  (ucr2a-east) -- node {\midarrow} (up1-west);
\draw [connection]  (ucr1a-east) -- node {\midarrow} (out-west);
%\draw [connection]  (out-east)   -- node {\midarrow} ++(2,0,0);

\path (cr4-southeast) -- (cr4-northeast) coordinate[pos=1.25] (cr4-top) ;
\path (cr3-southeast) -- (cr3-northeast) coordinate[pos=1.25] (cr3-top) ;
\path (cr2-southeast) -- (cr2-northeast) coordinate[pos=1.25] (cr2-top) ;
\path (cr1-southeast) -- (cr1-northeast) coordinate[pos=1.25] (cr1-top) ;

\path (cat4-south)  -- (cat4-north)  coordinate[pos=1.25] (cat4-top) ;
\path (cat3-south)  -- (cat3-north)  coordinate[pos=1.25] (cat3-top) ;
\path (cat2-south)  -- (cat2-north)  coordinate[pos=1.25] (cat2-top)  ;
\path (cat1-south)  -- (cat1-north)  coordinate[pos=1.25] (cat1-top)  ;
%
\draw [copyconnection]  (cr4-northeast)  
-- node {\copymidarrow}(cr4-top)
-- node {\copymidarrow}(cat4-top)
-- node {\copymidarrow} (cat4-north);
%
\draw [copyconnection]  (cr3-northeast)  
-- node {\copymidarrow}(cr3-top)
-- node {\copymidarrow}(cat3-top)
-- node {\copymidarrow} (cat3-north);
%
\draw [copyconnection]  (cr2-northeast)  
-- node {\copymidarrow}(cr2-top)
-- node {\copymidarrow}(cat2-top)
-- node {\copymidarrow} (cat2-north);
%
\draw [copyconnection]  (cr1-northeast)  
-- node {\copymidarrow}(cr1-top)
-- node {\copymidarrow}(cat1-top)
-- node {\copymidarrow} (cat1-north);

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide us with a complete code that starts with `\documentclass`, ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled. And please consider also making your question clearer. Which axis are you referring to?

Comment: @marmot Full code added

Comment: Well, `\subimport{../../layers/}{init}` fails if one does not have the `init` file. And I doubt that many have it. And I still do not understand which axis you are referring to.

Comment: I'm referring to ``zlabel`` as I mentioned in the question. The code is from here: https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet/tree/master/examples/Unet which I edited to my parameters. As can be seen from the pdf generated in the link the ``zlabel`` are aligned to centre. But when I edit the file and rebuild the centre alignment is lost

Comment: I get the `zlabel` correctly positioned as in the link, make sure you didn't edit the original files, `init, Ball, Box, RightBandedBox`, from the repo.

Comment: Thats strange. I checked manually and the files are exactly the same ``Box``, ``RightHandedBox``, ``init``, yet I don't seem to get the zlabel aligned to centre.

Comment: @StuckInPhD I am having the same issue, did you manage to find a way to fix it?

Comment: @Oxbowerce Unfortunately I could not get the z-labels to align as I wanted them and published the figures as is.

Comment: I actually managed to fix it by changing line 63 in `RightBandedBox.tex` from `pos=0` to `pos=0.5` as suggested by Jimmy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem than you! If you go in the RightBandedBox.tex file in the layers directory, you can change the position of the labels I at l.63 and write pos=.5 for instance. You can also swap "depthlabel" with "midway" at l.65.

Comment: You should _not_ change anything in the root at all!

Comment: Thanks StuckInPhDNoMore for asking and Jimmy for answering. The context missing from the original question is that this refers to example neural net diagrams in https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet

If you copy one of these examples (especially easy for the ones hosted at Overleaf as mentioned in the README.md) then you have a private version of RightBandedBox.sty which is simple to customize as desired. For my diagram, I turned off the “Banded-ness” and changed the placement for xlabel, ylabel, and zlabel relative to the oblique boxes.

Comment: If you are using the associated Python generator code, you need to be careful aboutf having your re-generations overwrite your customizations of RightBandedBox.sty